# Google SEO - new page not showing up in search result - Angular6

Tags: angular6, seo, single-page-application, meta-tags

I have to create a new page and make it standalone searchable on Google. My Application is in Angular 6. I have created a new ng component and defined the meta tags in app.routing like below -

```
{ path: 'test', data: { breadcrumb: 'test page', title: 'test page title',
      metaDescription: 'test page description', metaKeywords: 'keyword1, keyword2' }
    , component: TestComponent }
```

I am updating the header of the page on load of the component according to these meta data values. When I load the page I can see the updated meta title,keyword and description in the source code in browser for test page. But when I search on google by keyword1, keyword2 then the page is not showing up in search results, Infact I dont see the new page listed on sitemap of my website on google. Am I missing anything here?
Also is there anyway to test this google search in test environment?

Answer (score 1):

Google Crawlers take some time to index. it could take weeks also. if you want to index it before that then you need to submit your page url on google seaech console so that your new page can indexed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will need a `robots.txt` file. You can mention which search engines can crawl your website and which paths can it access. More info on https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608 and https://web.dev/robots-txt/